# Click house build is stuck after inserting user password

Tags: docker, dockerfile, devops, clickhouse

**Docker file**

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

ENV CH_VERSION 21.8.11.4
RUN \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get install --yes --no-install-recommends \
    apt-transport-https \
    apt-utils \
    dirmngr \
    gnupg && \
  apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv E0C56BD4 && \
  echo "deb http://repo.yandex.ru/clickhouse/deb/stable/ main/" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/clickhouse.list && \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get install --allow-unauthenticated -y \
    clickhouse-client=${CH_VERSION} \
    clickhouse-server=${CH_VERSION} \
    clickhouse-common-static=${CH_VERSION} \
    libgcc-7-dev \
    tzdata \
    libreadline-dev \
    curl && \
  rm -rf \
    /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    /var/cache/debconf \
    /tmp/* && \
  apt-get clean

VOLUME /var/lib/clickhouse

RUN chown -R clickhouse /etc/clickhouse-server

USER clickhouse
EXPOSE 9000 8123 9009

ENTRYPOINT exec /usr/bin/clickhouse-server --config=/etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml
```

When try to build clickhouse image by running following cmd

```
docker build -t clickhouse-server:21.8.11.4 .
```

After that, asking for default user password
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bse7P.png)

I have tried to insert blank password and also tried to insert random password, after inserting password it has gone stuck

Answer (score 1):

Setup

```
ENV CH_VERSION=...
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
```

look details in https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/explain-debian_frontend-apt-get-variable-for-ubuntu-debian/

Comment: After adding ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive build is create successfully but when i am running clickhouse image getting error 

/bin/sh: 1: exec: /usr/bin/clickhouse-server: Operation not permitted

Comment: add
```
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/clickhouse-server
```

before ENTRYPOINT

Comment: After adding "RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/clickhouse-server " before ENTRYPOINT

Error :
chmod: changing permissions of '/usr/bin/clickhouse-server': Operation not permitted